# When c# project add a reference to a c++/clr project, vs2008 seems doesn't copy the latest dll

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I have c# project A, and c++/clr project B, they are under the same solution S.
I make A reference B in vs2008 through "add reference" -> "project", however, each time after B is modified and rebuilt, A would not copy the new B's dll into its own "bin" directory.
How to fix that problem?
A simple method is write post-build event, but is there any direct method in vs2008 can be used to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the reference in the References node and check its Copy Local property in the Properties window.  Should be True.  Do check the build order and ensure B is always built before A.  Should be automatic but you can enforce it by right-clicking A, Project Dependencies.  There is otherwise no mechanism by which the build system is aware that the assembly was built with another compiler, it's just a DLL.

Comment: It seems doesn't work... I finally write a post-build command to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Check your output window and see if the project B is really building. If the output window says

```
Project not selected to build for this solution configuration,
```

you need to right-click the solution in `Solution Explorer` -> Configuration Manager -> Check Build for the project. I bet you might have changed your platform and that might have turned off the build of the project.